# What to do when poll_read's buffer has no sufficient size for my buffer?

Tags: rust

Rust's future uses `poll_read` ([poll_read](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.1/futures/io/trait.AsyncRead.html)) to poll for available data:

```
fn poll_read(
    &mut self, 
    cx: &mut Context, 
    buf: &mut [u8]
) -> Result<Async<usize>, Error>
```

Obviously, when called, the `poll_read` function fills `buf` with data and returns `Poll::Ready(n)` where `n` is the quantity written to the buffer. If there's no data available at the moment, it returns `Poll::Pending`. The future caller can `poll_read` again, **or not**. In the case where it does not poll again, it is giving the `poll_read` function the chance to tell when it has to be polled. It does that by calling `cx.waker().wake()` when there is available data.

So, for example, I can implement `poll_read` for my struct:

```
fn poll_read(
    &mut self, 
    cx: &mut Context, 
    buf: &mut [u8]
) -> Result<Async<usize>, Error> {
    let my_buffer = get_buffer_from_internet();
    if my_buffer.len() <= buf.capacity() {
        buf.put_slice(my_buffer);
        return Poll::Ready(my_buffer.len());
    } else {
        //we can only fill buf partially
        buf.put_slice(my_buffer);
        //let's store the remaining in our struct
        self.remaining.store(&my_buffer[buf.len()..]);
        //How can I make the future caller know it needs to call poll_read again to read the remaining data? Can I call cx.waker().wake() while inside the poll_read?
        return Poll::Ready(buf.len());
    }
}
```

you see that in the case where there was no sufficient space on `buf`, I copied just the needed data and then stored the remaining on our struct. So we can enhance this `poll_read` by making it check if there is remaining data to be written, before getting new data from the internet. But as you see in my comment: `How can I make the future caller know it needs to call poll_read again to read the remaining data? Can I call cx.waker().wake() while inside the poll_read?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do anything. The documentation reads:

> If no data is available for reading, the method returns `Poll::Pending` and arranges for the current task to receive a notification when the object becomes readable or is closed.

It does not need to arrange to be woken up if it returns data. The [implementation for `Cursor<T>`](https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.13/src/futures_util/io/cursor.rs.html#163-185), for example, just defers to `io::Read` and ignores the `Context` entirely, regardless whether the buffer is big enough or not.

The poller should know that there still may be data to read until `poll_read` returns `Poll::Ready(Ok(0))`.